# How do I log failed MediaWiki login attempts?

Tags: php, mediawiki

I cannot find a MediaWiki hook event for a failed login attempt. Does one exist? If not, does anyone know of a strategy for determining failed attempts?

In case there is another way - I am trying to log failed logins.

**EDIT**
Here is the pertinent bit of my code, the globals are set to the name of the wiki (I also tried the code offered in the comments):

```
$wgHooks['AuthManagerLoginAuthenticateAudit'][] = 'logAuth';
function logAuth($response, $user, $username)                                                                                                                                        
{                                                                                                                                                                                    
    // grab the MediaWiki global vars                                                                                                                                                
    global $fail2banfile;                                                                                                                                                            
    global $fail2banid;                                                                                                                                                              

    //set vars to log                                                                                                                                                                
    $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s T");                                                                                                                                                   
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];                                                                                                                                                   

    //successful login                                                                                                                                                               
    if ($response->status == "PASS") {                                                                                                                                               
        error_log("$time Successful login by $username from $ip on   $fail2banid\n", 3, $fail2banfile);                                                                                
        return true; //continue to next hook                                                                                                                                         
    } else {                                                                                                                                                                         
        error_log("$time Authentication error by $username from $ip on $fail2banid\n", 3, $fail2banfile);                                                                            
        return true; //continue to next hook                                                                                                                                         
    }
```

The above logs successful logins, and failed logins by registered users. Login attempts by unregistered usernames are not logged. I am using the logs with Fail2Ban.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [AuthManagerLoginAuthenticateAudit](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/AuthManagerLoginAuthenticateAudit) hook. E.g.

```
use MediaWiki\Auth\AuthManager;
use MediaWiki\Auth\AuthenticationResponse;

$wgHooks['AuthManagerLoginAuthenticateAudit'][] = function ( $response, $user, $username ) {
    if ( $response->status === AuthenticationResponse::FAIL ) {
        log( "Failed login for user $username" );
    }
};
```

---

To catch some cases which the above hook wouldn't, you can create a logging provider:

```
use MediaWiki\Auth\AbstractPreAuthenticationProvider;
use MediaWiki\Auth\AuthenticationResponse;

class LoggingAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractPreAuthenticationProvider {
    public function postAuthentication( $user, AuthenticationResponse $response ) {
        if ( $response->status === AuthenticationResponse::FAIL && $user ) {
            log( 'Failed login for user ' . $user->getName() );
        }
    }
}

$wgAuthManagerAutoConfig['preauth'][LoggingAuthenticationProvider::class] = [
    'class' => LoggingAuthenticationProvider::class,
];
```

Comment: The only logs failed attempts by registered uses. Right? I need to log attempts by unregistered usernames.

Comment: Users, not uses, sorry.

Comment: No, it logs all failed attempts. I added more details to the documentation, hope that helps.

Comment: I have tried a few different setups, based on your example. I am still not getting failed logins by unregistered users.

Comment: Well, you did something wrong. Hard to be more useful than that without seeing how you tried it.

Comment: I apologize for being unclear. I added the code that I am using. Thanks for the time you are putting into helping me.

Comment: The code seems fine (except that the right way to get the IP is `$this->manager->getRequest()->getIP()` but most of the time it does not make any difference). So it does not log anything when someone tries to log in with a non-existent username? Can you try to do that via the API (visit the page Special:ApiSandbox, set `action` to `clientlogin`, `loginreturnurl` to some URL, fill the token by clicking on the little icon on the right side of the textbox, add username + password fields at the end of the form and set them to some value) and tell what the response status is?

Comment: {
    "warnings": {
        "main": {
            "*": "Unrecognized parameters: username, password."
        }
    },
    "clientlogin": {
        "status": "FAIL",
        "message": "Authentication is not in progress or session data has been lost. Please start again from the beginning.",
        "messagecode": "authmanager-authn-not-in-progress"
    }
}

Comment: This kind of error is indeed not sent to the hook. But it does not fail due to a wrong username (the username & password never even gets examined), it fails because the session was lost. Do you see the same error when testing login attempts via unregistered users in the browser? If so, the browser might reject session cookies due to some overzealous privacy setting.

Comment: From the browser end, I just get "The supplied credentials could not be authenticated."  Incorrect password, with a registered username, gives a different error. Is there a way I can determine if the u & p are examined in the case of unregistered username attempts? I did examine the response headers

Comment: Oh, OK, I see what's going on. That's arguably a bug in MediaWiki (it does not call the hook when no authentication provider takes responsibility for the login attempt, and the username-password-localdb provider only takes responsibility if it recognizes the username) . As a quick fix, you can use an authentication provider for logging. I extended the answer with an example.

Comment: I was able to use the fact that AuthenticationResponse returns null on the username attribute if the user is not found. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Are you sure? I would think `$user` in `postAuthentication` will be null if the username is invalid and a valid User object with a name set if the username is valid but non-existent (existence can then be checked e.g. with `$user->isAnon()`).

Comment: $user seems to return whatever is entered in the auth  username field. I emailed a link to a gist with my total code